# Find count of numbers in a string in Java

Tags: java

I have a following string: 
"I have 22 bananas ,121 pencils, and p32 apples".

How can I write a code so that it returns the occurence of numbers in a string?

(it should output 3 in this case because there are 3 numbers)

Note: Number is defined as contiguous sequence of digits without any interruption in between.

public int countNums() {
    ...implement
}

Comment: You can use .split() to split on spaces.  Then Apache Commons has a helper method to determine if the value is a number.

Comment: Why three? Why not 14?

Comment: There are 3 numbers in the string

Comment: What should be answer for: "We don't have 3.5 tons of aluminium, but we have 4.25 liters of clean water, and we didn't realize that 1.217E-16 is unacceptable quantity"?

Comment: I would define number as contiguous sequence of digits without being interrupted by dot. Therefore only integer is considered as number here

Comment: You can use regex to find the numbers

Comment: I didn't down vote, but step by step can we agree that your question should be like "How can I find the number of occurrence(s) of integers in the string?"

Comment: So your solution is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *regular expression*. You can add more characters that could be around a numbers; I have added only few of them `\s - space` or `, - comma`:

```
public static int countNumbers(String str) {
    final Pattern standaloneNumber = Pattern.compile("(?<=[\\s,])\\d+(?=[\\s,])");
    Matcher matcher = standaloneNumber.matcher(str);
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (matcher.find(pos)) {
        pos = matcher.end();
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

> countNumbers("I have 22 bananas ,121 pencils, and 32 apples") - returns 3

Answer (score 0):

You can have a code as follows.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "I have 22 bananas , 121 pencils, and 32 apples";
        String[] sarr = s.split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for(String str : sarr) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(str);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sarr.length - count);
    }
}
```

In case if the number is having decimal Use double instead of Integer.

Comment: But what if "," is attached right in front of digit like this: ,121 ? Split wouldn't work in this case

Comment: Then you should have a regex that splits the string in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , it work to me

```
public static void main(String[]args){

     String str = "I have 22 bananas , 121 pencils12, and 32 apples";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");// numbers separated by spaces 
int o=str.trim().split(" ").length;// turn it to array and count the length
       System.out.println(o);
   }
}
```